# making a call to a template with parameters

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I am having an odd issue while trying to make a call to another template. I have a template that makes a call to another sub-template with multiple parameters. The issue I am having is that the sub-template(or called template) recognizes the very first parameter and throws exception for others as "Could not find variable with name ... ". When I try using a single parameter, it works fine: i can get the passed parameter value on called template but not when i am passing multiple parameters.

Here I have added the portion of code that defines parameters and makes a call to sub-template.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="subTemplatePerson"> <!--Making a call to sub-template-->
       <xsl:with-param name="personId" select="'ID123'"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="locale" select="'en_US'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
```

On the sub-template side:

```
   <xsl:template name="subTemplatePerson"><!--Template being called-->
      <xsl:param name="personId"/> <xsl:variable name="pId" select="$personId"/>
      <xsl:param name="locale"/> <xsl:variable name="localeValue" select="$locale"/>
   </template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to fix it by putting all `xsl:param` together at the beginning of the template.

Comment: Thank you!!! It is more weird now because in other called templates I have them the way I have explained in the problem and is working fine.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#local-variables says "xsl:param is allowed as a child at the beginning of an xsl:template element.".

Comment: @asp_NewBee That's not possible I'm afraid. `xsl:param` is either a top-level element or the first child of a template.